# "Unknown cmake command _add_executable" in Visual Studio 2017 when opening CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/ilasm/CMakeLists.txt using Visual Studio 2017 CMake tools.

However, when I use "Open folder" command in Visual Studio, I'm getting this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at C:\!Projects\coreclr-master\src\ilasm\CMakeLists.txt:44 (_add_executable):
Unknown CMake command "_add_executable".        C:\!Projects\coreclr-master\src\ilasm\CMakeLists.txt    44
```

The code piece:

```
_add_executable(ilasm
  ${ILASM_SOURCES}
  ${ILASM_RESOURCES}
)
```

What can I do to overcome this?

Comment: Are you using that CMakeList (`src/ilasm/CMakeLists.txt`) as your toplevel project (your source dir)? It doesn't seem to be designed for that, you're apparently supposed to use the project's top-level one (effectively `coreclr/CMakeLists.txt`)

Comment: Thanks. Now getting "CMake Error at functions.cmake:3 (message): Only AMD64, ARM64, ARM and I386 are supported". I'm on Win 10 Pro x64.

Comment: @Angew I also tried changing project target from x86 to x64 with no effect.